# Show that $x^2 + 3xy - 2y^2 = 1992$ has no solutions in integers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Here's what I did:**
I managed to write $x^2 + 3xy - 2y^2 = 1992$ as
$$\Big(2x+y\big(3 + \sqrt{17}\big)\Big)\Big(2x+y\big(3 - \sqrt{17}\big)\Big) = 7968$$
My doubt is that I have got a $\sqrt{17}$ in my factorisation as $y$ has to be $\sqrt{17},\sqrt{4,913}$ and so on which are not perfect roots, does this prove that $x$,$y$ are not integers?

Comment: $x^2-2y^2=(x+\sqrt2y)(x-\sqrt2y)=1$ does not mean that $x,y$ are not integers

Comment: OKㅤㅤ            ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any integers $x,y$, the product on RHS is always an integer, since it is equal to $(2x+3y)^2 - 17y^2$. Hence the factorization trick may not always work. For this question, consider modulo $3$.

Since $1992$ is divisible by $3$, by taking modulo $3$ we get:

$$x^2-2y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$$

Now $a^2 \equiv 0$ or $1 \pmod 3$. For the above difference to be divisible by $3$, both $x,y$ must be divisible by $3$.

But then $x^2 + 3xy-2y^2$ must be divisible by $9$, contradicting $9 \nmid 1992$.

Comment: Can you site the reason for using modulo 3 and not any other number?

Comment: I didn't get your last step where you said the expression must be a multiple of 9

Comment: If $x,y$ are both multiples of $3$, then $x^2, xy, y^2$ must be multiples of $9$.

Comment: ok thanks for your help

Comment: @AyushBhardwaj i think probably because if we took 2 it wouldn't prove anything because 4 | 1992 .

Comment: Yes. Besides, we can't go as far with $x^2 + xy \equiv 0 \pmod 2$, which can only imply that either $x$ is even or $x, y$ are both odd.

Answer (score 1):

I like [player3236](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/435724/player3236)'s solution a lot.  Here's an alternative.

It's $x^2+3xy+\frac94y^2-\frac{17}4y^2=1992$

or $\left(x+\frac32y\right)^2-\frac{17}4y^2=1992$

or $(2x+3y)^2-17y^2=7968\equiv12\bmod17$.

But $12$ is not a quadratic residue mod $17$, so there are no solutions.

Comment: Your method is nice as well